# Why am I getting $\beta=90^{\circ}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

Consider the geometry below, where the small circle is touching both semi circles of radius $5$ and the side of the square. Find the radius of the small circle.

[image]

My try: $M$ and $N$ are centers of semicircles and $G$ is center of small circle indicated below.Let $r$ be the radius of small circle.

[image]

We have
$$\beta=\frac{3\pi}{4}-\alpha$$

So we have

$$\sin \beta=\frac{\sin \alpha+\cos \alpha}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Also $$\sin \beta=\frac{r}{5-r}=\frac{\sin \alpha+\cos \alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{1}$$

By cosine law
$$\cos \alpha=\frac{(5-r)^2+(5 \sqrt{2})^2-(5+r)^2}{2(5 \sqrt{2})(5-r)}=\frac{5-2 r}{\sqrt{2}(5-r)}\:\Rightarrow \sin \alpha=\sqrt{\frac{2(5-r)^2-(5-2 r)^2}{2(5-r)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{25-2r^2}}{\sqrt{2}(5-r)}$$

Hence from $(1)$ we get
$$\frac{(5-2 r)+\sqrt{-2 r^2+25}}{\sqrt{2}(5-r)}=\frac{r}{5-r}$$
Solving the above equation we get $r=\frac{5}{2}$, but in that case $\beta=90^{\circ}$. Where I went wrong?

Comment: Is the small circle supposed to be tangent to both circles and the square edge? Because as drawn, the small circle intersects the left edge in two poinrs and one of the circles in two points.

Comment: its tangent...figure is little disturbed while creating

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the content of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The strategy is fine, but you have made an algebraic mistake: $\frac{(5-2 r)+\sqrt{-2 r^2+25}}{\sqrt{2}(5-r)}$ is only $\cos \alpha + \sin \alpha$, not $\frac{\cos \alpha + \sin \alpha}{\sqrt 2}$. Solving $$\frac{(5-2 r)+\sqrt{-2 r^2+25}}{2(5-r)} = \frac{r}{5-r}$$ instead gives $r = \frac{20}{9}$.

A simpler approach is to use the two right triangles below:

[image]

The larger right triangle (with height $h$) has $h^2 + (5-r)^2 = (5+r)^2$, from which $h = \sqrt{20r}$. Then, the smaller right triangle has $(h-5)^2 + r^2 = (5-r)^2$, from which $r = \frac{20}{9}$.

Answer (score 2):

This might be easier if you notice that that when two circles are tangent, then their tangent point is co-linear with their centers.

So if the lower left corner is the point $(0,0),$ then the center of your circle is $(r,y)$ where $r$ is the radius you seek, since the circle is tangent to the $y$ axis, and:

$$r^2+(y-5)^2=(5-r)^2$$ and $$(r-5)^2+y^2=(5+r)^2.$$

It is not hard to solve for $r$ from here.